# ¿Como Implementar el limites de correos entrantes en una bandeja de entrada?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una situacion, Tengo un Sitio que es un correo para Quejas y sugerencias de Clientes, pero se desequilibra su buen funcionamiento, puesto que llega a recibir hasta mas de 8000 correos..
Como puedo implementarle  un margen ???? , para decirle que despues 600 correos, no deje entrar mas a la bandeja, para que el sitio mantenga su buen funcionamiento tanto en conexion como su disponibilidad????

Comment: No se entiende bien. Como controlas la bandeja? que tiene que ver mysql con una bandeja de correo? a que apunta tu solucion?

Comment: Le comento, que se utiliza una base de datos donde se almacena todos los correos entrantes, es por ello que hice la pregunta, no puedo controlar la bandeja de entrada

Comment: Y tu solucion apunta a que esto este controlado por la base de datos o por quien? porque alguien ingresa los correos en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si ya tienes tu tabla de los correos electrónicos entonces será fácil, tienes tres opciones:

1. Crea un trigger tipo BEFORE donde antes de la inserción de la información valide si la longitud de correos recibido (por un rango, por día o por tu preferencia) es menor a 600, si lo es entonces que inserte el nuevo correo sino es así que regrese un valor nulo.
2. En la consulta desde tu service pon un validador antes de hacer la inserción, primero realiza la consulta donde si la tabla de correos ya llego a 600 entonces no permita la inserción de no ser así que realice la inserción.
3. Deshabilitar la opción de enviar quejas o sugerencias cuando el usuario ingrese a la ventana de quejas y sugerencias.